# vshost32.exe crashes when Running Crystal report

Tags: wpf, wcf, crystal-reports, vshost.exe

Im running an WPF app on Visual Studio 2010 (Platform x86). We're using a Client and server side using WCF. I've Implemented a Report functionality using Crystal by saving the report byte[] into our Postgress db, then when loading I load that into ReportDocument to get parameters then basically send that back server side and ExportToStream to create Report.

This has worked and has been running fine (old reports still do), but now we created a new Report and suddenly it crashes on ExportToStream popping up the (vshost32.exe has stopped working) box and the whole app crashes from there.

Is there anyone that encountered the same thing or can give me some suggestions? Been looking on Net but havn't found any real solutions.

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: (MYAPPNAME).vshost.exe
  Application Version: 10.0.30319.1
  Application Timestamp: 4ba2084b
  Fault Module Name: psqlodbc30a.dll
  Fault Module Version: 9.0.2.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4ccc3814
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00031910
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

Comment: Seems to be running when not opened through Visual Studio... but would like to figure out whats going on.. thx

Comment: Hate to sound flippant but don't debug it through VS. If it runs outside VS then if you need to debug you can just attach. I have had problems with WCF hosted in VS numerous times so now much prefer attaching to running process.

Comment: Thx for tip Hugh, tried the attach method but seems the problem is within Crystals DLL's (CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll) to be exact. Its the last DLL in my output on the attached service before it stops the service. 'MyService.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll'
The program '[6752] MyService.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 255 (0xff).

Comment: This sounds like a binding problem. You could run fusion log viewer to see exact errors on assembly binds. Some common things to check - delay signed assemblies, 64 bit assembly loading 32 bit assembly etc